# Deep copy a struct to another

Tags: c, struct, glib, deep-copy

I have a `struct` which contains strings and pointer within. Is there any library functions available to do a deep copy of the `struct` into another. I don't want to do a field by field copy since the struct I'm having is quite large.

Does glib have any function that does the trick?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use memcpy or memmove to copy the entire contents of the struct itself. However, as C has no introspection, copying pointed-to objects can't be done by a general purpose function.

Edited to add: As several commenters note, you can just assign structures to other structures in the C dialects in use for the last couple of decades, memcpy is not needed any longer.

Comment: You don't even need `memcpy`.  You can just do `a = b` for a shallow copy.

Comment: That is fairly recent, and some of us are old.

Comment: @Perry this is allowed since the first C Standard at least

Comment: @Perry: Hasn't it always been this way?

Comment: Nope. It hasn't always been that way. The name space of structs also used to overlap, which meant old timers had to name the struct tags in various patterned ways in order to avoid name clashes. Really. You can still see shadows of that in the names of various kernel structures in the BSD kernels, for example.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth before K&R C, it was not allowed. Look for the paragraph "By 1982 it was clear that C needed formal standardization..." in http://cm.bell-labs.com/who/dmr/chist.html

Comment: K&R didn't allow struct assignment either -- though that appeared in pcc pretty soon after K&R, as did the ability to pass structures directly to functions.

Comment: @Perry: Hmm, I'm not sure we're talking about the same language then!

Comment: It is pretty much the same language still, just a few conveniences have been added and we now get somewhat nicer declarations.

Answer (score 6):

No.  A general-purpose function would have no way to know the structure of your struct (i.e. the information that's only available at compile time).  And even if it did, how it would know what constitutes a "deep copy" in all circumstances?