# How to copy structure contents into another structure including pointers

Tags: c, data-structures

I am trying to deep copy from one structure to another structure
However structure has many pointers,how do I copy it in single statement?
Do I have to manually copy each structure pointer member?

Comment: A deep copy means copying not just the pointers, but the things the pointers point to. Yes, you must copy each thing; you can write a function that does all of that.

Comment: The structure is in one place in memory and each pointer that is not NULL contains the memory address of some other place in memory that is possibly far away.  memcpy only copies some bytes from a single address to another single address.  it doesn't know what those bytes do so it doesn't know they are pointers.  And assignment does memberwise copy so it copies the value of the pointer to the new struct (a shallow copy) - there is no operator that does a deep copy so you need to make your own function

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9473677/deep-copy-a-struct-to-another

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to manually copy everything if you want a deep copy.